# Get sorted Firestore documents when denormalizing data

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore for my app on which users can publish Posts, stored in the **posts** collection:

```
posts
    {postID}
        content = ...
        attachementUrl = ...
        authorID = {userID}
```

Each User will also have a timeline in which the posts of the people they follow will appear. For that I am also keeping a **user_timelines** collection that gets populated via a Cloud Function:

```
user_timelines
            {userID}
                  posts
                      {documentID}
                              postID = {postID}
                              addedDate = ...
```

Because the data is denormalized, if I want to iterate through a user's timeline I need to perform an additional (inner) query to get the complete Post object via its {postID}, like so:

```
    db.collection("user_timelines").document(userID).collection("posts")
    .orderBy("addedDate", "desc").limit(100).getDocuments() { (querySnap, _) in
        for queryDoc in querySnap.documents {
            let postID = queryDoc.data()["postID"] as! String
            db.collection("posts").document("postID").getDocument() { (snap, _) in
                if let postDoc = snap {
                    let post = Post(document: postDoc)
                    posts.append(post)
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is by doing so I am loosing the order of my collection because we are not guaranteed that all the inner queries will complete in the same order. I need to keep the order of my collection as this will match the order of the timeline.

If I had all the complete Post objects in the timeline collections there would be not issue and the `.orderBy("addedDate", "desc").limit(100)` would work just fine keeping the Posts sorted, but If I denormalize I cant seem to find a correct solution.

**How can I iterate through a user's timeline and make sure to get all the Post objects sorted by addedDate even when denormalizing data?**

I was thinking of creating a mapping dictionary postID/addedDate when reading the postIDs, and then sort the Post at the end using this dictionary, but I am thinking there must be a better solution for that?

I was expecting this to be a common issue when denormalizing data, but unfortunately I couldnot find any results. Maybe there's something I am missing here.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is enumerate the loop where you perform the inner query, which simply numbers each iteration. From there, you could expand the `Post` model to include this value `n` and then sort the array by `n` when you're done.

```
db.collection("user_timelines").document(userID).collection("posts").orderBy("addedDate", "desc").limit(100).getDocuments() { (querySnap, _) in
    for (n, queryDoc) in querySnap.documents.enumerated() {
        let postID = queryDoc.data()["postID"] as! String
        db.collection("posts").document("postID").getDocument() { (snap, _) in
            if let postDoc = snap {
                let post = Post(document: postDoc, n: n)
                posts.append(post)
            }
        }
    }
    posts.sort(by: { $0.n < $1.n })
}
```

The example above actually won't work because the loop is asynchronous which means the array will sort before all of the downloads have completed. For that, consider using a Dispatch Group to coordinate this task.

```
db.collection("user_timelines").document(userID).collection("posts").orderBy("addedDate", "desc").limit(100).getDocuments() { (querySnap, _) in
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
    for (n, queryDoc) in querySnap.documents.enumerated() {
        dispatch.enter() // enter on each iteration
        let postID = queryDoc.data()["postID"] as! String
        db.collection("posts").document("postID").getDocument() { (snap, _) in
            if let postDoc = snap {
                let post = Post(document: postDoc, n: n)
                posts.append(post)
            }
            dispatch.leave() // leave no matter success or failure
        }
    }
    dispatch.notify(queue: .main) { // completion
        posts.sort(by: { $0.n < $1.n })
    }
}
```